# MVC razor form ONLY submits when last DropDown is populated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I actually found a solution. It was trying to run validation. But only the last validation was added. The message for validation was not displaying.

I can NOT figure this out. I have a form that is created using razor like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "WellSearch", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.Partial("_DropDownList_Operator", Model)                           

@Html.Partial("_DropDownList_Lease", Model)

<input type="submit" id="buttonClearAllFields" class="btn btn-small submit" name="Command" value="ClearAllFields" />
<input type="submit" id="buttonSearch" class="btn btn-small submit" name="Command" value="Search" />
}
```

What is wired is this I can ONLY submit form when the last DropDown is populated with a value. If I leave both drop downs blank can't post to a controller. Also if I switch the order of the drop downs around make Operator last it is the same thing.

I my actual code I have 10 total drop down boxes the same thing only the last one is populated. I know MVC pretty well but not an expert.

My question is this what should I check to troubleshoot this behavior. I check everything no errors, no exceptions. Not sure how to troubleshoot this need an advice what to be aware of or maybe someone was in a same situation.

This is a code for a partial view

```
@model [removed].Models.[removed]

@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.[removed].LeaseKey, new { id = "lease"})
```

[removed] - removed those because it contains personal information

Comment: Can you provide the code of the partial views?

Comment: @GoshaFighten added a partial view to my question.

Comment: @Html.Partial("_DropDownList_Lease", Model) why are you doing partial view just for a dropdown list

Comment: Post your Model also... I suppose your "Dropdownlist" are "Required". BTW, I see a TextBoxFor instead of a DropDownListFor.

Comment: The partial you have shown dies not have a dropdown!

Comment: @COLDTOLD this is actually a select2 drop down. Where else should it go?

Comment: what do you mean select2 select2 drop down

Comment: Yes. This http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: You do not need partial view to use that

Comment: Anyway... the examples in "Select2" uses DropDownLists not TextBox to work. Replace the @Partial... for the actual @Html.DropDownListFor() you use inside de Partial. You will get mad later in your project with lots of partials.

Comment: @Romias Yes I agree about a lot of partials. Also Html.DropDownListFor() for select2 that is not what they use. There is an actual MVC project implementing select2 they use Html.TextBoxFor

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution. It was trying to run validation. But only validation for lease drop down was added. The message for validation was not displaying.